# I want to select same Table same column to separate Desc_Main and Desc_sup by cdValuse

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I want to separate to Desc_Main and Desc_Sup from cdValue

1. 100000 are main and have sup value is '101000','102000' from cdValue
2. 200000 are main and have sup value is '201000','202000' from cdValue

[image: This is the result pic]

i want to show in this table

[image: I want to show this result pic]

My Script

```
 SELECT 
          cdValue
        , Desc_sup  =   CASE Left(cdValue,3)
                        WHEN '100' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '200' THEN cdDesc_th
                        ELSE cdDesc_th END 
        ,
         Desc_Main  =   CASE Left(cdValue,3)
                        WHEN '101' THEN cdDesc_th 
                        WHEN '102' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '103' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '104' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '105' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '106' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '201' THEN cdDesc_th
                        WHEN '202' THEN cdDesc_th
                        ELSE cdDesc_th END
        FROM SellingAgent..tb_LookupCode (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE cdType='Cat_FAQ'
```

Please help me to use Case-when Thank you very much

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Can you please create schema and sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @D-Shih SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I think you need another record to show the relation between main and sup values.

Comment: @iminiki the main and sup values is the new value setting that use cdValue by separate to Desc_Main and Desc_Sup like the picture two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBMS version is `2012+` then, may use `first_value()` function

```
  with tb_LookupCode(cdValue, Desc_sup, Desc_Main) as
          (
           select 100000, 'FAQ','FAQ' union all
           select 101000, 'Philip Fund','Philip Fund' union all   
           select 102000, 'LTF&RMF','LTF&RMF' union all
           select 200000, 'Article','Article' union all
           select 201000, 'Financial Article','Financial Article'  
          )
   select first_value(cdValue) over 
          (partition by substring(cast(cdValue as varchar(25)),1,1) 
           order by cdValue)
          as cdValue,
          first_value(Desc_sup) over 
          (partition by substring(cast(cdValue as varchar(25)),1,1) 
           order by substring(cast (cdValue as varchar(25)),1,1))
          as Desc_sup,
          Desc_Main
     from tb_LookupCode l;

cdValue Desc_sup    Desc_Main
------- -------- ------------------ 
100000   FAQ          FAQ
100000   FAQ       Philip Fund
100000   FAQ        LTF&RMF
200000  Article     Article
200000  Article   Financial Article
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/OYIW39996)

Comment: In SQL Server, you should not use `varchar` without a length.  The default length varies by context, and it might not always work.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you sir, i can use it.